# Is a Gradle file affected when you add new files

Tags: github, gradle

On Github while working with my friend on some code (actually experimental malware for pentesting), we set up a Gradle check, and it failed. When it ran, it said this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'wurstplus-two'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.3-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.3-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo.spongepowered.org/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://repo.spongepowered.org/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://repo.spongepowered.org/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 520 from server: Origin Error
   > Could not resolve org.spongepowered:mixingradle:0.4-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I know we added some files, so I was thinking that might be what happened. I don't know any Gradle, so that's really why I'm asking.

There's actually 2 questions: What does "exit code 1" mean, and was it triggered by those new files being added? The Github repository is here: https://github.com/Scottw1e/wurstplus-two.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should first of all look at the entire log output, and not just the very last line, to get an understanding of the error. Once you do, and you see things like `Could not GET 'http://repo.spongepowered.org/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 520 from server: Origin Error`, and you still don't know what that means, you can ask a more specific question on why it happens. Be sure to include the log output though, or you are sure to get down-voted as your question currently lacks details.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your time to answer my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `http://repo.spongepowered.org/maven/` with `https://repo.spongepowered.org/maven/` in your build.gradle file

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It didn't work though :(

Comment: This seems to fix the issue for me.